# "id" attribute in microformats

Tags: html, microformats

Is the "id" attribute allowed in microformats? Example ([hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) microformat):

```
<div class="tel" id="voice">
  <span class="type">Voice</span>
  <span class="value">(206) 555-1234</span>
</div>
<div class="tel" id="fax">
  <span class="type">Fax</span>
  <span class="value">(206) 555-5678</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is allowed but ignored by the standard. All [properties have to be declared by classes](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard#Properties_and_Sub-properties):

> Elements with class names of the listed properties represent the values of those properties.

Comment: But it's ok to use the id attribute for purposes of CSS styling?

Comment: Yes, of course. They don’t conflict with your hcard declarations.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm Gumbo's answer. The id attribute won't affect microformat parsing. It's perfectly acceptable for formatting use, anchoring, etc.